# warning: no previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'c' [-Wmissing-variable-declarations]

Tags: vector, startup, extern, keil

I saw the following code provided by `keil`:

```c
/* in cmsis_armclang.h */
...
#define __VECTOR_TABLE            __Vectors
...
#define __VECTOR_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE  __attribute__((used, section("RESET")))
...

/* in system_ARMCM3.h */
...
typedef void(*VECTOR_TABLE_Type)(void);
...

/* in startup_ARMCM3.c */
...
extern const VECTOR_TABLE_Type __VECTOR_TABLE[240];
       const VECTOR_TABLE_Type __VECTOR_TABLE[240] __VECTOR_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE = {
  (VECTOR_TABLE_Type)(&__INITIAL_SP),       /*     Initial Stack Pointer */
  Reset_Handler,                            /*     Reset Handler */
...
```

I don't understand why the `__VECTOR_TABLE` array needs to be declared with the extern keyword before it is defined.

When I remove the extern statement, a warning will appear during compilation.

```bash
RTE/Device/ARMCM3/startup_ARMCM3.c(80): warning: no previous extern declaration for non-static variable '__Vectors' [-Wmissing-variable-declarations]
       const VECTOR_TABLE_Type __VECTOR_TABLE[240] __VECTOR_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE = {
                               ^
D:/ProgramData/Arm/Packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.9.0/CMSIS/Core/Include/cmsis_armclang.h(128): note: expanded from macro '__VECTOR_TABLE'
#define __VECTOR_TABLE            __Vectors
                                  ^
RTE/Device/ARMCM3/startup_ARMCM3.c(80): note: declare 'static' if the variable is not intended to be used outside of this translation unit
       const VECTOR_TABLE_Type __VECTOR_TABLE[240] __VECTOR_TABLE_ATTRIBUTE = {
             ^
1 warning generated.
```